# jdbc Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost'; mysql does not require password

Tags: java, mysql, tomcat, jdbc

My tomcat servlet on a ubuntu system was running normally and suddenly broke down. I restarted tomcat, and the servlet cannot connect to mysql any more.
I also found that mysql does not require a password when I log in. 
Here is the code of the servlet:

```
        Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
Connection conn=DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/larryxu","root","");
```

I can access mysql with the same servlet on my own computer, so I think the problem is on the mysql server.
Here is the stack trace in catalina.out:

```
java.sql.SQLException: Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost'
    at com.mysql.jdbc.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:964)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.checkErrorPacket(MysqlIO.java:3973)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.checkErrorPacket(MysqlIO.java:3909)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.checkErrorPacket(MysqlIO.java:873)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.proceedHandshakeWithPluggableAuthentication(MysqlIO.java:1710)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.doHandshake(MysqlIO.java:1226)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.coreConnect(ConnectionImpl.java:2205)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.connectOneTryOnly(ConnectionImpl.java:2236)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.createNewIO(ConnectionImpl.java:2035)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.<init>(ConnectionImpl.java:790)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.JDBC4Connection.<init>(JDBC4Connection.java:47)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:423)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.Util.handleNewInstance(Util.java:425)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.getInstance(ConnectionImpl.java:400)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.NonRegisteringDriver.connect(NonRegisteringDriver.java:330)
    at java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(DriverManager.java:664)
    at java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(DriverManager.java:247)
    at larryxu.MainServlet.recordVisitor(MainServlet.java:82)
    at larryxu.MainServlet.doPost(MainServlet.java:49)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:661)
 at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:742)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:230)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:165)
    at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:53)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:192)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:165)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:199)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:96)
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:475)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:140)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:80)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.AbstractAccessLogValve.invoke(AbstractAccessLogValve.java:624)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:87)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:341)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.service(Http11Processor.java:498)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProcessorLight.process(AbstractProcessorLight.java:66)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$ConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:796)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1368)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SocketProcessorBase.run(SocketProcessorBase.java:49)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
```

Comment: Is your MySql server still running? Are you able to connect through another client?

Comment: Try replace 'localhost' in the connection string to the server's FQDN, i.e. the same as how you connect to it from your own computer.

Comment: The server is running. I can connect through the shell

Comment: I mean I can connect to the mysql server on my own computer with the same java code. I am using exactly the same url on my own computer.

Comment: The database is sending you that exception. And it is telling you: You are not allowed to login as root without a password. Probably you are in fact NOT connecting from the localhost so you need to grant access from within the database to connect outside of the localhost too.

Comment: Is everything running on the same computer? Tomcat and the MySql database?

Comment: Yes. They are running on the same computer

Comment: Check your mysql configuration file. see #skip-networking is like this (commented), and that bind-address  = 127.0.0.1 for localhost access, or 0.0.0.0 for access from any network interface card.

Comment: I don't have these in my my.cnf